# is there a way to lock everything so settings won't get changed between rendering sessions?

Tags: rendering

Say you are rendering in images so you can pick up where you left off, if need be, is there a way to lock down everything that needs to be locked, like camera position so when you start again the frames settings will not be off when putting it all together into a move when finished, it will be as if one never stopped rendering until the finished product.

I've looked for locking but have not found anything this specif on it.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding the question, but isn't that the purpose of keyframes: Defining values for specific frames so the animation always looks the same?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but if you render as PNG rather than a movie you can then render any number of frames at anytime and then make them into a movie in the VSE. Also there is "Save As" using the "+" button to make unique incremental file names to preserve settings. And you can click the "+" next to "Scene" at the top of the screen and "Full Copy" to make sure you do not lose anything.

Comment: being new, the animation within the camera frame moves not the camera, if by accident something, or many objects r moved by hitting the wrong key. like the mouse wheel, it can move the camera around so the scene is no longer like it was in the viewer looking through the camera, what do I need to set so that I will always get the original starting point of everything if I am interrupted during rendering, just to be sure that when putting all of the images into a movie their is not a jarring effect because something got misaligned in the middle of the process of rendering the entire project out.

Comment: ugg, I do not know all of the proper jargon for this. Not the exact starting point per se' but the camera frame and everything within that frame set up, so that everything stays as it was suppose to when first setting up and rendering from start to finish. I'm going to go check out this click '+' thing to see what that is all about.if that is just making up a back up file, then that is not what I am trying to convey here.

Comment: OK I found some tab called transform locks, does each object have their own, so it would require locking everything down separately  via within that tab for each separate object. I'm guessing.

Comment: Instead of writing endless comments, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and try to reformulate your question. It is hard to understand what you are doing and how to help you. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: OK Joe. sorry...

Comment: Don't edit title of the question with Solved please. You can accept your own answer instead

Comment: it didn't let me, and why is there not conformity among help forums? ok its telling me I have to wait 17 hours to tell myself I was right.. yeah Ok... that is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformation Locks is what you need to use to lock down everything that needs to be locked. Each object has its own LOCKS for LOCKING it down to prevent it from moving.